# Why can not determine the in-order traversal of a tree when given its pre-order and post-order traversals?

Tags: data-structures, tree, inorder, preorder, postorder

We are all familiar with pre-order, in-order and post-order traversals of binary trees. A common problem in data structure classes is that:

- Find the pre-order traversal of a binary tree when given the in-order and post-order traversals.
- Alternatively, you can find the post-order traversal when given the in-order and pre-order.
- However, in general you **cannot** determine the in-order traversal of a tree when given its pre-order and post-order traversals.

I want to why and is there a good way to explain it theoretically?

**Update 1**
one answer: there will be problem with leaves whose parent has only 1 child because in such case such leaf can be either left or right child.

Comment: What kind of explanation are you looking for?

Comment: @Ranveer some mathematical explanation like that, I think.

Comment: But since you're **disproving** something, plain logic works, right?

Comment: Are you asking about a binary tree in general, or a binary search tree?

Comment: @JimMischel, a binary tree in general, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a theoretical explanation of this, but I'll try to explain it logically.

Let's take a more general problem :- Construction of a binary tree using pre-order and post-order traversals.

Let's take an example. We have the following tree:

```
    1
   / \
  2   5
 / \   \
3   4   6
```

The pre order for this tree will be (1,2,3,4,5,6) and the post order will be (3,4,2,6,5,1). Now, we wish to reconstruct the same tree.

We know that 1 is the root node. Now we go to 2. In the post order, since 2 is before 1, it's a child of 1. 3 is next. Since 3 is before 2, it's a child of 2. 4 is before 2, and hence is it's child. 5 is after 2 but before 1, so it's a child of 1 but not 2. 6 is a child of 5 similarly. But is 6 the left child or the right? We have two possibilities here:

```
    1              1  
   / \            / \
  2   5          2   5
 / \   \        / \ / 
3   4   6      3  4 6
```

With no way to determine whether 6 is the left or right child of 5. In case of 2's (and similarly 1's) children, we're sure since 3 comes before 4 in the post order traversal (left-tree, right-tree, root) but in case of a single child, there is an ambiguity.

Hence, for a binary tree that isn't complete, one **cannot** unambiguously determine the tree and hence the in-order traversal (though you **can** if the tree is complete).

Comment: How do you detect that the tree is complete? And how do you know that, for instance, 3 is before 2 and not after 2 in an incomplete tree? In other words, how can you tell that the tree is not just a completely degenerated tree going towards left or right?